# Save XML to the server a file generated by PHP

Tags: php, xml

After some searches on the web and some tests, i can't find the solution and need your help

From a php script, i create a XML output  :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
//some code
echo $xml->asXML();
```

I Would like to create a file contain the XML and save on my server by using PHP.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what were you searching for that gave you no solution? solutions to this are easily available.  search on google for `php write text to file`.  the first result is spot on.

Comment: ok but i thought for xml that was different  . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `echo $xml->asXML()` displays the xml then I guess you could use `file_put_contents` or other similar function. ie:

```
$filepath='/path/to/directory/filename.xml';
file_put_contents( $filepath, $xml->asXML() );
```

Comment: Sometimes developpers looks for something difficult... Often, coding is more simple that i can imagine  Thanks a lot guy!